# Вызов формы при двойном клике по строке DataGrid

Tags: c#

Реализую на C# с использованием MySQL архив статей газет.

Есть две таблицы: основная - edition - выпуски газет со столбцами id_edition, number и date и подтаблица publications - список статей, написанных в выпусках со столбцами id_publication, id_edition, name, keywords.

Как реализовать через CellContentDoubleClick вызов формы AddPublications, которая будет привязана именно к id_edition выбранной строки?

Comment: ну, вам по идее надо форму вторую описать и потом в обработчике двойного клика её создать (например `var myForm = new AddPublications(/* ваши параметры, что нужны для формы*/);`) и после форму показать `myForm.Show();` и, по сути, всё

Comment: В чем проблема - получить id_edition ?